# Failed to get mock metadata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Running jest and getting an error, not sure what to do about it.

**MenuSpec.js**

```
//MenuSpec.js
var Menu = require('../../src/menu.js');
jest.dontMock( "menu" );

describe("Menu", function() {
    

    beforeEach(function() {
        menu = new Menu();
    });
});
```

getting this error in particular

```
Error: Failed to get mock metadata: /Users/[me]/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/parrit/node_modules/react/lib/canDefineProperty.js
    at Loader._generateMock (/Users/[me]/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/parrit/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:251:15)
```

**Project structure**

```
/js
  /__tests__
    /menu
      MenuSpec.js
  /src
    menu.js
```

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json, add this to your jest configurations.

```
"jest": {
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react"
  ]
}
```

Depending on what other modules you are using you may need to include them too.

```
"jest": {
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/fbjs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I had to use only the module names. Perhaps this is a recent change?  "jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react"
    ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

Jest is trying to mock React, it shouldn't.

Use the config parameter [unmockedModulePathPatterns](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-unmockedmodulepathpatterns-array-string) to tell Jest unmock React

Secondly, you have to unmock a module **before** requiring it:

```
jest.dontMock( "../../src/menu" );
var Menu = require('../../src/menu');
```