# Jest tests failing with no metadata

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babel-jest, ts-jest

Have unit test that fails with a specific error message.

```
 Test suite failed to run

    Failed to get mock metadata: <path-to-project>/node_modules/lodash/_freeGlobal.js

    See: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks.html#content
```

The source of the problem seems to be the `lodash/isEmpty` usage in application code. The dependency ultimately narrows to the `_freeGlobal.js` which exports `global` object. The jest(using jest-mocks library) is unable to get the metadata for this object as it doesn't recognize the type.

**Question: Is there a way for me to mock the global object or make Jest correctly mock `global` returned by lodash?**

I exactly know where the problem happens.

> - Jest iterates through each imports in my typescript file
> - Determines each module to the last level,
> - goes through mocking them via jest-mock
> - Here in jest-mock it [tries to getMetadata](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/6499debdaa4fde3cc83ad1f42b3210478a389026/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L299-L337)
> - As part of the metadata it tries to get the [type name here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/6499debdaa4fde3cc83ad1f42b3210478a389026/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L299-L337)
> - And since `Object.prototype.toString.call(global)` emits `[object Window]`, it is unable to detect typeName `window` at which point it
>   errors out.

**Environment**

```
"jest": "24.9.0",
"jest-cli": "24.9.0",
"jest-dom": "4.0.0",
"ts-jest": "24.2.0",
"@types/jest": "24.0.25",
"babel-jest": "24.9.0",
```

**Jest config:**

```
"jest": {
  "automock": true,
  "preset": "ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "roots": [
    "./app/cdap/"
  ],
  "modulePaths": [
    "./app/cdap/"
  ],
  "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "./app/cdap/components/AbstractWidget/SchemaEditor/Context/__tests__/schemas.js",
    "./app/cdap/components/AbstractWidget/SchemaEditor/Context/__tests__/data"
  ],
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/lodash/isEmpty",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/lodash/round",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/lodash/cloneDeep",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    ".scss$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMocks.js",
    "/^components/": "<rootDir>/app/cdap/components",
    "/^services/": "<rootDir>/app/cdap/services",
    "/^api/": "<rootDir>/app/cdap/api",
    "^lib": "<rootDir>/../lib",
    "^mocks": "<rootDir>/__mocks__"
  },
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "babelConfig": {
        "plugins": [
          "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**
Have tried suggestions [from other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847150/failed-to-get-mock-metadata) . As I keep adding specific lodash modules to the `unmockedModulePatterns`, eventually my own module gets mocked and all my tests fail.

```
"unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/lodash/isEmpty",
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/lodash/round",
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/lodash/cloneDeep",
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom"
],
```

Comment: Are you saying that specifying unmockedModulePathPatterns option enables automock in your own modules from src? I'm not sure if it's supposed to work this way, but you can try to add `"<rootDir>/(?!node_modules)"` pattern there to prevent this. Just a note, a lot of times automock does more harm than good, and enabling it globally is efficiently a footgun. Packages like Lodash are crossplatform and side effect-free, there's no harm in keeping them unmocked in tests.

Comment: Ah! Wasted on this for 5 days. Yes. automocks: false fixed most of the issues. Thanks a ton @EstusFlask. This was the right approach.